Redis, sorted set with pagination Node js
I have a list of posts. I want to get the posts in a paginations.
Right now I am using hash key to store pagination data in redis. The issue I am facing now whenever any updates in post made then I need to flush whole hash key.
To get rid of this I have decided to sorted redis.
But problem is here, let say poll data has been added by others users and currently I am on second page, in that case duplicate post can be shown.
Please help me with this
parameters  from clients are page=0 and page_size=2 then command will be zrevrange(key, 0, 2*1 -1 ) and result is [10,9].  similarly for next request page=1 and page_size=2 then command will be  zrevrange(key, 2, 2*2 -1 )   and result is [8,7]
